# Indexed by Int64 and not number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a dataframe with ~800,000 rows. However, the dataframe is indexed from 0 to 5746 when displaying, which I don't understand why. I thought that maybe only a few rows were displayed but if I select the last hundred rows, this still persists.
[image: See picture here.]

In my previous projects, my dataframes always have the same number of rows and the displayed index.
[image: See picture here.]

Can someone please explain what's going on? My process is identical to my previous works so I don't see how the indexing is changing, and why.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicated index. Check it with:

```
>>> df.index.value_counts()
```

But if the index doesn't matter, drop it:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: What led to the duplicated indices? Also, I reset the indices and it shows the correct thing. On re-runs, the duplicates re-appear.

Comment: You have to reassign the output to the `df`. I updated my answer. Can you check it please? Most of functions of pandas returns a new dataframe, so you have to set to a variable.

Comment: That's fine and all, but I'm trying to understand what causes duplicated indices in the first place?